# PyScripter: Why might some modules import personal modules while others dnot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror, pyscripter

I am using PyScripter to implement a lesson from the Python Tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules

However, when I attempt to import my own module `quadform.py` in a separate code by calling

```
import quadform  
quadform.quad_form(1,1,-6)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quadform'
```

Even more confusing is that when I copy + paste the exact code into a separate module saved in the same location, the import on the second module does works.  Since then, I have tried various permutations of syntax, using different IDEs, calling from different modules, calling from the shell, and fiddling with the Path in Environment Variables with only a few successes and seemingly at random.

Can someone explain what might be the issue?  At the moment, I cannot reliably call any of my modules without getting the same error.  I am a beginner trying to pick up Python (and programming in general) on my own so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Read further down:

- https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path
- https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/modules.html#packages
- https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

If you structure your modules like it says, you should be able to import the right things. `sys.path` is a list of the folders Python looks in to find packages.

Comment: As far as I know, what I am trying to import is not a package.

I did try to read up more about the search path because I think that's what this issue is related to.  Since posting the question, I have been able to consistently import my modules by importing `sys` and appending the location to `sys.path` first.  However, I can sometimes import the `quadform.py` module without the preliminary lines.  And when I called `sys.path` in the interpreter, I confirmed that the location I normally have to append is not on the search path.

So I am still not clear on what is happening in the code.

Comment: And my overall goal is to learn how to avoid adding those preliminary lines.  I understand that they have their purpose, but for what I am trying to accomplish, they are too clunky and inefficient.